# More than one request at the same time in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt about handing in more than one request at a time in php. I have a php function say insertOrder() to insert the details to a database table and send notifications to the users. The details will be posted from another source automatically to this function. These are the steps in the insertOrder()

1. Start Mysql transaction
2. Select the order count from the database table where orderId=123 ( From the post data )
3. If count= 0 then insert the database table and send the notifications
4. If is not 0 then update the order
5. Commit

The problem is that sometimes the system will send the data with the same id to the inserOrder() at the same time. In that time, `Select the order count from the database table where orderId=123` will be always 0 so that it will try to insert both post details to the database table. Even though i am using the mysql transaction, it is inserting duplicate rows. what may be the reason? If anyone knows, please help me to sort it out.

The following are the two sample data to the inserOrder()

`{orderId:123,status:pending}`

`{orderId:123,status:completed}`

When we get the data first time to the insertOrder(), the order Id 123 will not be there in the database table so it will insert it into the database table and the second time it should update the database table value. Since it is getting both data at the same time it is inserting into the database table.

This is the code snippet of insertOrder

```
function insertOrder()
{
    $orderId = $_POST['orderId'];
        
    
    try
    {
        start transaction

            $order = select from table where orderId=$orderId

        if(count($order) == 0)
            Insert the order
            commit
        else
            update order where orderId=$orderId
        }
    catch()
    {
        rollback
    }
}
```

Comment: are the rows duplicate or do they have the same id with different order data? Where are you generating the order id#?

Comment: please share your php code fragment\

Comment: Why not let the database assign the orderId?

Comment: I have just updated the question and added the post data to the function. Could you please check it?

Comment: Check what? The given "code snippet of insertOrder" does not contain valid PHP code

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert rows with duplicate IDs, then you do not have a `UNIQUE` constraint on this column. If you make it unique, then the last transaction will fail to be committed.

You have at least two options for this:

1. Primary key is what generally used for ID columns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

2. Just a unique constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (id);
```

Note that it is unusual to allow client to choose IDs for records that are inserted. Most of the time you should allow the DB to pick the next ID for entities like orders.

Comment: H Alexey, Thanks for the reply. I can't add it as primary, actually is orderId field in the database. I have updated the question, i already have a primary key `id` in the table.

Comment: OK, then it is not a primary key. But why are you refusing to use `UNIQUE`? Are there circumstances under which there could be legitimate rows with the same orderId? What are they?